# List of Algorithms with toptesi

Tags: algorithms, toptesi

I am using the `algorithm` package to create a list of algorithms in my thesis written with `toptesi` by Claudio Beccari. However, I am having trouble including the list of algorithms in the table of contents. Currently, I am generating the lists and table of contents using the commands `\figurespagetrue \tablespagetrue \indici`. Is there a way to include the list of algorithms in the table of contents, or is there a command that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a redefinition of `\indici` to produce and include the list of algorithms (with captions) when `\algospagetrue` is invoked before `\indici`.

The algorithms are numbered in the same style as the tables and figures (adding the chapter number).

Use `\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{<title>}` to change the name of the list of  algorithms.

[image: a]

.

[image: b]

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex

 \documentclass[%
    corpo=13pt,
    twoside,
%    stile=classica,
    oldstyle,
    autoretitolo,
    greek,
    evenboxes,
%    tipotesi,
]{toptesi}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% si può scegliere anche latin1, ma lo si sconsiglia fortemente
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%%*********************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{algpseudocode} % added here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{algorithm} % added here <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\newif\ifalgospage
\algospagefalse

\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{Elenco degli algoritmi}% to change the list name <<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand{\indici}{%
    \iffrontmatter\else\frontmattertrue\fi
    \tableofcontents
    \iftablespage
    {\addvspace{10pt}
        \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace%
        \def\addvspace##1{}
        \listoftables
        \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
    \fi
    \iffigurespage
    {\addvspace{10pt}
        \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace%
        \def\addvspace##1{}
        \listoffigures
        \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
    \fi
    \ifalgospage % added <<<<<<<<<<
    {\addvspace{10pt}
        \let\saveaddvspace=\addvspace%
        \def\addvspace##1{}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listalgorithmname}
        \listofalgorithms
        \let\addvspace=\saveaddvspace}
    \fi
    \ifbool{@twoside}{\cleardoublepage[empty]}{}}
    \let\allcontents\indici
    \onecolumn
    \if@twoside
    \unless\ifScuDo
    \flushbottom
    \else
    \raggedbottom
    \fi
    \else
    \ifx\@xivpt\f@size
    \raggedbottom
    \else
    \flushbottom
    \fi
    \fi
    \brokenpenalty=10000
    \def\interlinea#1{\linespread{#1}\selectfont}
    \def\endinterlinea{\par}
    \def\@floatboxreset{%
        \reset@font
        \linespread{1}%
        \normalsize
        \@setminipage
}
\makeatletter 
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{\thechapter.\arabic{algorithm}}  % add  the chapter number to the algorithm number <<<<
\@addtoreset{algorithm}{chapter} 
\makeatother    

%%**********************************************    
\usepackage{hyperref} % must be last package <<<<<<<<<<<<

\hypersetup{%
    pdfpagemode={UseOutlines},
    bookmarksopen,
    pdfstartview={FitH},
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={blue},
    citecolor={blue},
    urlcolor={blue}
}

\begin{document}


\tablespagetrue
\figurespagetrue
\algospagetrue % to produce and include the list of algorithms to the indice  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\indici

\mainmatter

\part{Prima Parte}
\chapter{Introduzione generale}
\lipsum[1]

Le grandezze in gioco sono evidenziate nella figura \ref{fig:orbita}.
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\caption{Orbita del generico satellite; si noti l'eccentricit\`a dell'orbita rispetto al pianeta.}\label{fig:orbita}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Il barometro}

Il mercurio gode della sorprendente qualit\`a et propriet\`a, cio\`e che esso
diventa tanto solido da potersene fare una testa di martello et infiggere
chiodi aguzzi nel legname.

\begin{table}[htp!]              % crea un floating body col nome Tabella nella
\centering                      % comando necessario per centrare la tabella
\caption[Densit\`a del mercurio]{Densit\`a del mercurio} \label{t:1}  % didascalia con label
\end{table}

\chapter{Diversi algoritmi}

\begin{algorithm}[ht!]
    \caption{An algorithm with caption}\label{alg:cap}
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \Require $n \geq 0$
        \Ensure $y = x^n$
        \State $y \gets 1$
        \State $X \gets x$
        \State $N \gets n$
        \While{$N \neq 0$}
        \If{$N$ is even}
        \State $X \gets X \times X$
        \State $N \gets \frac{N}{2} $  \Comment{This is a comment}
        \ElsIf{$N$ is odd}
        \State $y \gets y \times X$
        \State $N \gets N - 1$
        \EndIf
        \EndWhile
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!